# What is a Coefficient ring in Ring theory?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

In lecture, a (well, actually, two words) word "coefficient ring"-without having been defined-was used in the theorem

> Theorem:
>
> If the coefficient ring $D$ is an integral domain then so is its polynomial ring $D[x]$.

What is a coefficient ring? Is a coefficient ring the coefficient of each term in a polynomial ring?

Comment: $D$ is any ring. It is only called a "coefficient ring" because it is used for the coefficients of the polynomials in $D[x]$.

Comment: @almagest, almagest is right. In different language: coefficient ring is basically a meaningless term.

Comment: To be sure, D is just the non-empty subset, consisting of coefficients of the polynomials in D[x], that forms a ring. Am I right?@goblin

Comment: @Mathematicing, the theorem you quote can be read: "If $D$ is an integral domain, then so too is $D[x]$." Does that answer your question? "coefficient ring" doesn't really mean anything

Comment: @goblin Certainly clear if expressed as that.

Answer (score 2):

Let $p$ be polynomial in $D[x]$. Then, we can write $p = \sum_n a_nx^n$. We call $a_n$ coefficients of polynomial $p$, and we can say that $D$ is coefficient ring of $D[x]$ since all coefficients are members of ring $D$, and any member of $D$ can be coefficient of a polynomial in $D[x]$.

Answer (score 1):

A coefficient ring is a complete noetherian local ring with finite residue field of characteristic p. (Cornell, Silverman, Stevens, DEF by Mazur.)

Comment: I seriously doubt that the lecturer meant this. This is basic theorem in any introductory course in algebra.